# How can I upload MeshRegions to Mathematica.SE?

Tags: export, import, mesh

I know how to upload images to Mathematica.StackExchange. But what about `MeshRegions`? That's something I'd like to do frequently. Best would also be a programmatic way to load the region back into Mathematica.

For very simple regions, I can upload some code to generate them or even their coordinates and polygons as plain Mathematica code. But that certainly has its limits. I would also prefer not to use external services as it frequently occured to me that DropBox or Google Drive do not work as expected.

So, is there any way to upload MeshRegions to this site?

Comment: I feel like this should be migrated to [meta] since this is a support question for using this particular site... unless the title and usage can be generalized like "How to transfer MeshRegions data as an image?"

Answer (score 9):

I developed a simple routine `ExportMeshRegionAsImage` that exports the `MeshRegion` into two images that can be uploaded to SE.

First, `ExportMeshRegionAsImage` rescales the coordinates of the `MeshRegion` `R` into the unit box and converts the coordinates into an `Image` of size `{MeshCellCount[R,0], RegionEmbeddingDimension[R]}` and stores it as png (I use png because it of its lossless compression; that's crucial for not compromising the data). Essentially the same is done with the polygons, but I generate an image from *digits* of the index list. <s>Currently, only triangle meshes are support because I use the the a color channel per triangle corner.</s>

```
Options[ExportMeshRegionAsImage] = {
   "RowLength" -> 4096,
   "CoordinateFormat" -> "png",
   "CoordinateOptions" -> {},
   "CellFormat" -> "png",
   "CellOptions" -> {}
   };
ExportMeshRegionAsImage[file_String, R_MeshRegion, OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Module[{pts, triangles, s1, s2, a, b, shift, scale, ϵ, 
    data, rowlen},
   ϵ = 0.0005;
   rowlen = OptionValue["RowLength"];
   pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
   {a, b} = List @@ BoundingRegion[pts];
   shift = 0.5 (a + b);
   pts -= ConstantArray[shift, Length[pts]];
   scale = (1. + 2 ϵ) Max[Abs[b - a]];
   pts /= scale;
   pts += 0.5;
   a = Join[{1.}, 
     Join @@ Riffle[IntegerDigits[Dimensions[pts]]/10., {{1.}}], {1.},
      Flatten[pts]];
   s1 = Export[
     file <> "_pts." <> OptionValue["CoordinateFormat"],
     Image[
      ArrayReshape[a, {Ceiling[Length[a]/(3 rowlen)], rowlen, 3}, 0.],
       "Real"],
     Sequence @@ OptionValue["CoordinateOptions"]
     ];

   data = 
    N[PadLeft[
       IntegerDigits[
        MeshCells[R, RegionDimension[R], "Multicells" -> True][[1, 
          1]]]]]/10.;
   a = Join[
     {1.}, Join @@ Riffle[IntegerDigits[Dimensions[data]]/10., {{1.}}],
     {1.}, Flatten[data]];
   s2 = Export[
     file <> "_cells." <> OptionValue["CellFormat"],
     Image[
      ArrayReshape[a, {Ceiling[Length[a]/(3 rowlen)], rowlen, 3}, 0.]],
     Sequence @@ OptionValue["CellOptions"]
     ];
   Association["CoordinateFile" -> s1, "CellFile" -> s2, 
    "Scale" -> scale, "Shift" -> shift]
   ];

Options[ImportImageAsMeshRegion] = {
   "Scale" -> Automatic,
   "Shift" -> Automatic,
   "CoordinateFormat" -> "tiff",
   "CellFormat" -> "png"
   };

ImportImageAsMeshRegion[a_Association] := Module[{opts},
   opts = Merge[{
      Options[ImportImageAsMeshRegion],
      a
      }, Last];
   ImportImageAsMeshRegion[
    opts["CoordinateFile"], opts["CellFile"], 
    Normal@opts[[Keys[Options[ImportImageAsMeshRegion]]]]
    ]
   ];

ImportImageAsMeshRegion[file_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  ImportImageAsMeshRegion[
   file <> "_pts." <> OptionValue["CoordinateFormat"],
   file <> "_cells." <> OptionValue["CellFormat"],
   opts
   ];

ImportImageAsMeshRegion[file1_String, file2_String, 
   OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{pts, cells, cell},
   pts = Module[{a, pos, meta, dims, databegin, dataend},
     a = Flatten[ImageData[Import[file1, "BitDepth" -> 64]]];
     pos = Partition[Flatten[Position[a, 1.]], 2, 1];
     meta = Table[Take[a, p + {1, -1}], {p, pos}];
     dims = 
      FromDigits /@ Round[10. Table[Take[a, p + {1, -1}], {p, pos}]];
     databegin = pos[[-1, -1]] + 1;
     dataend = databegin + Times @@ dims - 1;
     ArrayReshape[a[[databegin ;; dataend]], dims]
     ];
   pts -= 0.5;
   If[NumberQ[OptionValue["Scale"]],
    pts *= OptionValue["Scale"]
    ];
   If[VectorQ[OptionValue["Shift"]],
    pts += ConstantArray[OptionValue["Shift"], Length[pts]]
    ];

   cells = Module[{a, pos, dims, databegin, dataend},
     a = Flatten[ImageData[Import[file2]]];
     pos = Partition[Flatten[Position[a, 1.]], 2, 1];
     dims = 
      FromDigits /@ Round[10. Table[Take[a, p + {1, -1}], {p, pos}]];
     databegin = pos[[-1, -1]] + 1;
     dataend = databegin + Times @@ dims - 1;
     Map[FromDigits, 
      ArrayReshape[Round[10. a[[databegin ;; dataend]]], 
       dims], {Length[dims] - 1}]
     ];
   cell = Switch[Dimensions[cells][[2]],
     2, Line,
     3, Polygon,
     4, Tetrahedron,
     8, Hexahedron
     ];
   If[cell === Tetrahedron && Dimensions[pts][[2]] == 2, 
    cells == Polygon];
   MeshRegion[pts, cell[cells]]

   ];
```

This is how it works:

Example mesh

```
R = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "MeshRegion"];
```

[image]

Exporting:

```
opts = ExportMeshRegionAsImage["test", R]
```

> <|"CoordinateFile" -> "test_pts.png", "CellFile" -> "test_cells.png", 
>    "Scale" -> 0.155855, "Shift" -> {-0.0168404, 0.00153695, 0.110154}|>

You can reinport from file with `ImportImageAsMeshRegion[opts]`. However, upload to SE will rename the images and this is why there is also a two-argument version of `ImportImageAsMeshRegion`: The first argument is the image file for the coordinates and the second is for the triangles lists. Optional argumens`"Scale"` and `"Shift"` can be given for redoing the normalization that was done during export.

The uploaded images `"test_pts.png"` and `"test_triangles.png"` are here:

[image]

[image]

You can download the images and convert them back with

```
S = ImportImageAsMeshRegion[
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8G0R.png",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCdYy.png",
  Normal@opts[[{"Scale", "Shift"}]]
  ]
```

[image]

Since png support only 16 Bit per channel, there is a considerable amount of rounding error:

```
Max[Abs[MeshCoordinates[R] - MeshCoordinates[S]]]
MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]] == 
 MeshCells[S, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]
```

> 1.18906*10^-6
>
> True

This can be repaired by using the tiff format and 64bit color depth"

```
opts = ExportMeshRegionAsImage["test", R,
   "CoordinateFormat" -> "tiff",
   "CoordinateOptions" -> {"BitDepth" -> 64}
   ];
T = ImportImageAsMeshRegion[opts];
Max[Abs[MeshCoordinates[R] - MeshCoordinates[T]]]
```

> 1.38778*10^-17

Unfortunatly, this produces of course a file of significantly larger size that also cannot be uploaded to SE. But 16 bit may suffice for providing simple examples anyway...

Comment: I was planning on asking and self-answering a question with my workflow on detecting plagarism in Mathematica coursework, but I wanted to include a set of .nb files to make it complete. Would something similar work for that?

Comment: The point here is that a `MeshRegion` can be fully described by two arrays. The .nb format is _much_ more complicated. You could try to convert the notebook to a `String`, convert each character to a number between  1/2^16 and 1 export that as a 16 Bit png...

Comment: @KraZug we have a GitHub: https://github.com/stackmma might be worth putting there. Or your own GitHub pages. halirutan also has a way to compress arbitrary Mathematica expressions as images to put here via his SEUploader, too.